# How to get from DirectoryEntry to SPuser

Tags: active-directory, spuser

I need to get the SPuser for a partcular directory entry.

What I need to do is get all the users from an AD group and give them permissions to a list item. The code is:

```
SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();
DirectoryEntry myDirectoryEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get username Domain name from DirectoryEntry. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941002/how-can-i-get-domain-user-from-an-ad-directoryentry

After you get the domainname you can get SPUser object as :

```
SPUser user = SPWeb.EnsureUser(loginName);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should help:

```
 var domainName = "<yourdomainname>";
 var completeAccountName = "";
 var accountName = myDirectoryEntry.Properties.Contains("samaccountname")
                            ? Convert.ToString(myDirectoryEntry.Properties["samaccountname"][0])
                            : string.Empty,

 // The Active Directory returns account name without domain name.
 if (!accountName.StartsWith(domainName))
 { completeAccountName = domainName + "\\" + accountName; }

 SPUser user = SPWeb.EnsureUser(completeAccountName);
```